# Python to print out to excel or csv from a for loop

Tags: python

I have working on this code:

```
Section = {'East':['Alan','Bob'],
           'North':['Alan','Michael'],
           'South':['Tom'],
           'West':['Bob','Michael','Tom']}
Name = {'Alan':['Subaru','Chevvy','Honda'],
        'Bob':['Toyota','Honda','Camry'],
        'Michael':['Camry','Ford'],
        'Tom':['Ford','Toyota']}
Inventory = {'East':['Toyota','Honda','Camry'],
             'North':['Ford','Chevvy','Ferrari','Subaru'],
             'South':['Subaru','Acura','Lexus','BMW'],
             'West':['Ford','Subaru','Camry']}



for name,sections in Section.items():
    for section in sections:
        haveInventory = Name[name]
        needInventory = Inventory[section]
        
        for inventory in needInventory:
            if inventory not in haveInventory:
                print(str(name) + ' ' + str(section) + ' ' + str(inventory))
```

1. Not sure what but the code does not run
2. How can i export the result out to excel or csv file with the following format:
   Alan  East  Camry
   Alan  East  Honda
   Tom   South  Subaru

Comment: It isn't running because pair of items will be section, names, not name, sections, e.g. `'East', ['Alan','Bob']`... So when you do the lookup in the others dictionaries, you are looking for `Name['East'] `(Key error), `Inventory['Alan']`(Key error)...

Comment: _the code does not run_ What does that mean? _How can i export the result out to excel or csv file_ What exactly is the issue? Have you done any research on how to write CSV files in Python? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I have changed these two lines:

```
for name,sections in Section.items():
    for section in sections:

To


for sections,names in Section.items():
    for name in names:
```

---

```
import csv

Section = {'East':['Alan','Bob'],
           'North':['Alan','Michael'],
           'South':['Tom'],
           'West':['Bob','Michael','Tom']}
Name = {'Alan':['Subaru','Chevvy','Honda'],
        'Bob':['Toyota','Honda','Camry'],
        'Michael':['Camry','Ford'],
        'Tom':['Ford','Toyota']}
Inventory = {'East':['Toyota','Honda','Camry'],
             'North':['Ford','Chevvy','Ferrari','Subaru'],
             'South':['Subaru','Acura','Lexus','BMW'],
             'West':['Ford','Subaru','Camry']}


f1 = open('file.csv','w')
writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
for sections,names in Section.items():
    for name in names:
        haveInventory = Name[name]
        needInventory = Inventory[sections]
        
        for inventory in needInventory:
            if inventory not in haveInventory:
                print(str(name) + ' ' + str(sections) + ' ' + str(inventory))
                writer.writerow([f"{name} {sections} {inventory}"])
```

---

```
Alan East Toyota
Alan East Camry
Alan North Ford
Alan North Ferrari
Michael North Chevvy
Michael North Ferrari
Michael North Subaru
Tom South Subaru
Tom South Acura
Tom South Lexus
Tom South BMW
Bob West Ford
Bob West Subaru
Michael West Subaru
Tom West Subaru
Tom West Camry
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
for name,sections in Section.items(): # ('East', ['Alan','Bob'])
    for section in sections:
        haveInventory = Name[name] # Name['East'] Causes error
        needInventory = Inventory[section]
```

As you can see, in that particular iteration, you are trying to get value of the key `'East'` from the dictionary `'haveInventory'`, but that dictionary doesn't have that key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Section = {'East': ['Alan', 'Bob'],
           'North': ['Alan', 'Michael'],
           'South': ['Tom'],
           'West': ['Bob', 'Michael', 'Tom']}
Name = {'Alan': ['Subaru', 'Chevvy', 'Honda'],
        'Bob': ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Camry'],
        'Michael': ['Camry', 'Ford'],
        'Tom': ['Ford', 'Toyota']}
Inventory = {'East': ['Toyota', 'Honda', 'Camry'],
             'North': ['Ford', 'Chevvy', 'Ferrari', 'Subaru'],
             'South': ['Subaru', 'Acura', 'Lexus', 'BMW'],
             'West': ['Ford', 'Subaru', 'Camry']}

import pandas as pd
result=pd.DataFrame()
NAME = []
SECTION = []
INVENTORY = []
for section, names in Section.items():
    for name in names:
        haveInventory = Name[name]
        needInventory = Inventory[section]

        for inventory in needInventory:
            if inventory not in haveInventory:
                print(str(name) + ' ' + str(section) + ' ' + str(inventory))
                NAME.append(name)
                SECTION.append(section)
                INVENTORY.append(inventory)

data = {'Name': NAME, 'Section': SECTION, 'inventory': INVENTORY}
result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Section', 'inventory'])
result.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i am looking for. Did not know how to parse the result with panda dataframe to print it out.

Comment: I am happy to hear that.

Comment: Note: Saving in this way can lead to memory error if the dataset is too large. Better to save line by line.

Comment: How can i save the data line by line ? - nvm, i saw the code below with the line by line instruction. Thank you :)

Comment: You can check the answer below from Pygirl. Also please check this post stackoverflow.com/questions/8078330/csv-writing-within-loop. You may add also timestamp if needed when saving the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import gmtime, strftime, time
import csv
current_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", gmtime())


with open('result_'+ current_time + '.csv','w') as f1:
    writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
    for section, names in Section.items():
        for name in names:
            haveInventory = Name[name]
            needInventory = Inventory[section]

            for inventory in needInventory:
                if inventory not in haveInventory:
                    print(str(name) + ' ' + str(section) + ' ' + str(inventory))
                    writer.writerow([str(name) + ' ' + str(section) + ' ' + str(inventory)])
```

Comment: This is almost same as Pygirl answered, the only difference is that you have timestamp in the csv name (in case you need it or want to prevent overwriting the existing file).